# compute time taken by a function in android using threads

Tags: android, multithreading

How can I compute the time taken by a function or request using **threads**? In more details, calling **start** function before the function to be measured and calling **end** function after it. One more thing, if I want to measure the time taken by **multiple functions** how can I do that? How to link end function with its **corresponding** start function. Any help will be much appreciated.

Can I write something like this?

```
public void start() {
long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
thrd = new Thread( new Task(start) );
thrd.start();
}

public void end() {
thrd.interrupt();
}

class Task implements Runnable{

    long start;

    Task(long start)
    {
        this.start = start;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if( Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() )
        {
            myHandler.post(new Runnable(){      
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    long end = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    long elapsed = end - start;             
                }       
            });//post           
        }//if
    }//run
}//Runnable
```

Comment: It seems like com.jakewharton.hugo

Answer (score 0):

before your function starts:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

after your function ended:

```
long difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;


difference / 1000
```

will give you the difference in seconds. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually,I know this, but how can I use this in threads